# getApplicationThread() on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

tengo un problema realizando el intent para abrir otra activity, si yo realizo:
`startActivity(Intent("dam.android.carlos.customview.DAUSPOINT"))`
en el metodo "onCreate", la aplicación se abre nada más iniciarse, pero yo quiero que ese intent se realize cuando yo pulso sobre un botón en otra activity, por lo que he realizado lo siguiente:

```
 fun abrir() {

    startActivity(Intent("dam.android.carlos.customview.DAUSPOINT"))


}
```

Y llamo a este método cuando compruebo que usuario y contraseña son iguales:

```
 private fun comprobarUsuario(user: String, passwd: String) {

    if (user.equals(passwd)) {

        var main = MainActivity()
        main.abrir()

    } else {
        Log.i("loge", "Error ")
    }

}
```

Pero al realizarlo así, me sale el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
```

En la línea 32, que es cuando realizo el srtatActivity en el fun abrir().
Alguna sugerencia de donde podría estar el error? 
Gracias.

**EDITO:**
Siguiendo las instrucciones, agrego aqui la clase completa:

```
package dam.android.carlos.customview

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }


    fun abrir() {

        var intent = Intent (this, MainDaus::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }


}
```

Y el error que me muestra al ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
 Process: dam.android.carlos.customview, PID: 3425
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:145)
    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:131)
    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6510)
    at dam.android.carlos.customview.MainActivity.abrir(MainActivity.kt:36)
    at dam.android.carlos.customview.CustomComponent.comprobarUsuario(CustomComponent.kt:72)
    at dam.android.carlos.customview.CustomComponent.access$comprobarUsuario(CustomComponent.kt:15)
    at dam.android.carlos.customview.CustomComponent$$special$$inlined$let$lambda$1.onClick(CustomComponent.kt:58)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

La linea 36 del MainActivity.kt es donde declaro el intent, antes del startActivity.

En cambio si pongo el intent del mismo modo que lo tengo en el metodo, en el onCreate, no me sale el error y se ejecuta nada mas abrir la aplicación.

La clase entera donde llamo a `comprobarUsuario()` es la siguiente:

```
package dam.android.carlos.customview

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_custom_component.view.*

class CustomComponent @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) {
    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_component, this, true)
        orientation = VERTICAL

        attrs?.let {
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                it,
                R.styleable.custom_component_attributes, 0, 0
            )
            val title = resources.getText(
                typedArray
                    .getResourceId(
                        R.styleable
                            .custom_component_attributes_custom_component_title,
                        R.string.userCarlos
                    )
            )

            my_title.text = title
            my_edit.hint = "${resources.getString(R.string.passwd)} $title"
            btnAcceder.text = "${"Acceder a "}$title"
            val titulo = "" + title
            titulo.toLowerCase()
            val context = imagen.getContext()
            val id = context.getResources()
                .getIdentifier(titulo.toLowerCase(), "drawable", context.getPackageName())

            imagen.setImageResource(id)

            var user: String
            var passwd: String
            btnAcceder.setOnClickListener {

                user = my_title.text.toString()
                passwd = my_edit.text.toString()

                comprobarUsuario(user, passwd)

            }
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }

    private fun comprobarUsuario(user: String, passwd: String) {

        if (user.equals(passwd)) {

            var main = MainActivity()
            main.abrir()

        } else {
            Log.i("loge", "Error ")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `Intent` necesita un primer parámetro que es el contexto. Prueba así: **`startActivity(Intent(this,"dam.android.carlos.customview.DAUSPOINT"));`** Puedes usar también el nombre de la clase, si se llama `DAUSPOINT` puedes hacer: **`startActivity(Intent(this,DAUSPOINT::class.java));`**  Sugeriría que respetes la convención de nombres. Las clases y activis no deberías nombrarse  en UPPERCASE.

Comment: También probé a hacer lo que comentas, si yo en el onCreate pongo: 
`var intent = Intent (this, MainDaus::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)`
se abre la activity nada más inicar la aplicación, pero si lo pongo en el metodo `fun abrir()` que es el metodo que llamo cuando compruebo la contraseña, me sale el siguiente error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta cómo tienes el método ahora y agrega también la traza del error NPE, indicando en qué línea ocurre ese error.

Comment: Vale, acabo de editar la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Tu clase extiende de `AppCompatActivity`? Si es posible pon la clase completa como la tienes ahora para ver el contexto completo. Veo que te falta usar `new` al crear el `Intent`, en esta línea: `var intent = Intent (this, MainDaus::class.java)` dado que usas Kotlin, no sé si esto es permitido en ese framework ¿?

Comment: He puesto la clase completa, y como ves, si que extiende en AppCompactActivity. En Kotlin no es necesario realizar el `new` al crear el `Intent`. Lo que no logro entender es porqué en el metodo `onCreate` funciona sin problemas, y nada más abrir la aplicación realiza el intent, y en cambio cuando está dentro de la función para que se abra cuando se le llame salga ese error...

Comment: Pero no veo desde dónde llamas a tu método `abrir()` ¿? Y, ¿por qué sobre escribes el método `onCreate` de una activity Main? ¿No se supone que esa es tu clase principal? ¿O acaso estás enlazando aplicaciones distintas o algo así?

Comment: El método `onCreate` se sobrescribe cuando generas una activity nueva. Al principio de la pregunta muestro donde llamo al método `abrir()`.
La aplicación lanza una pantalla splash que dura unos segundos, para mostrarte un login - proceso que hace correctamente- si introduces la contraseña bien, mostrarte un juego de dados - al hacer el intent de los dados es cuando falla -

Comment: Ok perdona por ese *lack* sobre el `onCreate`. Sigo sin entender cómo se relaciona el método `abrir()` con la Activity. ¿Dónde está el método `comprobarUsuario()` desde el cual llamas a `abrir()`
? Pon el contexto completo para poder analizarlo.

Comment: En el metodo `comprobarUsuario()`, se declara un `MainActivity()`, el cual se llama `main`, y luego lo llamo meidante `main.abrir()`, de todas formas he puesto toda la case para que se pueda ver el contexto entero.

Comment: Prueba así a ver si funciona: `var intent = Intent (this@MainActivity, MainDaus::class.java)` es extraño que si lo llamas en el `onCreate`  funcione pero no en un método.

Comment: Nada, me sale el mismo error que muestro en la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo que hize fue lo siguiente:
La clase CustomComponent se quedó tal que asi:

```
class CustomComponent @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) {
    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_component, this, true)
        orientation = VERTICAL

        attrs?.let {
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                it,
                R.styleable.custom_component_attributes, 0, 0
            )
            val title = resources.getText(
                typedArray
                    .getResourceId(
                        R.styleable
                            .custom_component_attributes_custom_component_title,
                        R.string.userCarlos
                    )
            )


            my_title.text = title
            my_edit.hint = "${resources.getString(R.string.passwd)} $title"
            btnAcceder.text = "${"Acceder a "}$title"
            val titulo = "" + title
            titulo.toLowerCase()
            val context = imagen.getContext()
            val id = context.getResources()
                .getIdentifier(titulo.toLowerCase(), "drawable", context.getPackageName())

            imagen.setImageResource(id)


            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }

}
```

Y en lugar de llamar al metodo abrir() desde ahí, lo que hice fue declarar los edit text de usuario y contraseña en el MainActivity(), y cojer los datos desde el main, y abrir la siguiente activity desde ahí:

```
lateinit var acceder : Button
    lateinit var usu : EditText
    lateinit var passwd : EditText
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        acceder = findViewById(R.id.btnAcceder)
        usu = findViewById(R.id.my_title)
        passwd = findViewById(R.id.my_edit)
        acceder.setOnClickListener {

            if(usu.text.toString().equals(passwd.text.toString())){

                abrir()
            }

        }

    }

    fun abrir() {

        var intent = Intent (this, MainDaus::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }


}
```

Y así obviamente si funciona, no se porqué quería hacerlo de la manera tan difícil en la que lo estaba planteando al principio... Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda de todos modos.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque al momento de declarar el MainActivity() no está teniendo ningún context por eso sale error de null

`fun abrir(context: Context)`

Enviar el context de tu actividad actual.

Comment: He realizado las modificaciones siguientes: `fun abrir(context: Context) {
        var intent = Intent (context, MainDaus::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }` y desde donde llamo a `fun abrir()` he puesto lo siguiente: `var main = MainActivity()
            main.abrir(context)` pero me sale el mismo error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference`